# How to test PHP code a user submits through a textarea

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write a couple of simple PHP questions that people can solve. For example, a questions could be to write a little script that sorts a given array. Another questions could be to write a piece of code that creates a certain object with a couple of methods.

I then want to validate the answers a user submits through a textarea, along the times of what codecademy is doing.

What would be the preferred way to validate PHP code that was submitted in such a way? Perhaps I can somehow run PHPUNIT or another testing framework against the submitted code, but it has to happen in the browser, not locally.

A good starting point would be to understand how http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ works when submitting PHP code.

Comment: You're setting yourself up for a dangerous situation. Allowing a user's PHP code to be executed on your machine is not for the faint of heart. You *could* use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but make very sure you're running a user's code in a sandbox that will not affect your system.

Comment: Maybe you will need some kind of API that receives PHP code, executes it and returns answer of execution. According to this answers you will be able to evaluate user's code or give him some remarks.